# Can't uninstall Microsoft SQL Server 2016 RC3

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 RC3 was installed on our server (not by me) Windows Web Server 2008 R2 64bit.  Visual Studio 2015 Community was also installed.  When I went to work on the server I could not connect to the MS SQL Server, so I went to see if the service was running and the only MS SQL service in the services manager was:

> SQL Server VSS Writer Provides the interface to backup/restore
>   Microsoft SQL server through the Windows VSS infrastructure.

None of the core services were installed.  When I looked in the start menu all the Microsoft SQL Server 2016 RC3 programs were installed.  When I ran the Installed SQL Features Discovery Report, it showed MS SQL 2016 installed, but no instances.

So I uninstalled VS, and attempted to uninstall MS SQL Server.  I uninstalled the main program and all the components and then attempted to uninstall Microsoft SQL Server 2016 RC3 Setup, but it pops up the following message:

> Warning 26003. Microsoft SOL Server 2016 Ro3 Setup Support Files
>   cannot be uninstalled because the following products are installed:
>   SOL Server 2016 Ro3 Batch Parser SOL Server 2016 Ro3 SOL Diagnostics
>   SOL Server 2016 Ro3 XE vent SOL Server 2016 Ro3 Shared Management
>   objects
>
> Extensions SOL Server 2016 Ro3 SOL Diagnostics SOL Server 2016 Ro3
>   Batch Parser SOL Server 2016 Ro3 XE vent SOL Server 2016 Ro3 Shared
>   Management objects

Yet none of these show in the Add/Remove Programs. (I refreshed it several times)

I then ran the Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Release Candidate 3 (RC3) Setup Discovery ReportMicrosoft SQL Server 2016 Release Candidate 3 (RC3) Setup Discovery Report, and it just has a single line with None in all the boxes.

I then attempted to reinstall Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Release Candidate 3, by running setup from the downloaded ISO, and Installation/New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation/

I am trying to install the evaluation version and that is what was previously installed, when I get to the Feature Selection of the wizard it shows the following:

> Shared Features/Reporting Services - SharePoint Shared
>   Features/Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Products

So none of the core services are available to install.

The ISO I am installing from is: SQLServer2016RC3-x64-ENU.iso, downloaded from Microsoft, and I have used the exact same ISO to install on a Windows 10 machine with VS 2015 installed with no problems and did not have this issue.

How can I resolve this and get Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Release Candidate 3 installed and running?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand), I was able to resolve the issue following the manual steps outlined in his blog:

- [Fun with software : uninstalling SQL Server 2008 R2 Evaluation Edition](https://sqlblog.org/2010/10/25/fun-with-software-uninstalling-sql-server-2008-r2-evaluation-edition)

...in spite of the title, it's not just for 2008 R2 or Evaluation Edition.

In case the link ever stops working, the essential steps are:

1. Locate SQL Server related GUIDs under:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
   ```
2. Also look for GUIDs in folders under *Uninstall* called e.g. "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2"
3. Run for each item:

   ```
   msiexec /x "{guid}"
   ```